# How I can convert a Color into MaterialColor so I can have a limited Pallete of colors in my App?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

For my application I wanted to limit my palette of colors therefore I made a class full of constants containing instances of Colors:

```
class Colors 
{
  static var red = Color(0xFFFF1212);
  static var blue = Color(0xFF1212FF);
  static var green = Color(0xFF12F1FA);
}
```

But sometimes a `MaterialColor` is required. So somehow I need to convert a Color instance into a `MaterialColor` instance. But the constuctor requires to offer a swatch (some sort of pallete for it). How I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An approach of mine is inspired by this [article](https://medium.com/flutterworld/flutter-material-color-conversion-ad1574f25828). The way I do it, is to use various opacity channels, with fixed values at red, green and blue channels. Color also is stored  in seperate red, green and blue channels that are accessible via instance variables, according to this [Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html).

Having these pieces of puzzle I made this function:

```dart
 MaterialColor getMaterialColor(Color color) {
    final int red = color.red;
    final int green = color.green;
    final int blue = color.blue;

    final Map<int, Color> shades = {
      50: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .1),
      100: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .2),
      200: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .3),
      300: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .4),
      400: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .5),
      500: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .6),
      600: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .7),
      700: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .8),
      800: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .9),
      900: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, 1),
    };

    return MaterialColor(color.value, shades);
  }
```

With the code above I perform the following:

1. I extract the Red Green and Blue channels
2. I place an opacity for a fixed shades
3. I use the manufactured shades and place them into `MaterialColor`

I know I could use a second parameter with the number of shades but it was too much hassle for me. In my case having some sort of fixed shades is good enough.

Answer (score 8):

```
MaterialColor getMaterialColor(Color color) {
final int red = color.red;
final int green = color.green;
final int blue = color.blue;
final int alpha = color.alpha;

final Map<int, Color> shades = {
  50: Color.fromARGB(alpha, red, green, blue),
  100: Color.fromARGB(alpha, red, green, blue),
  200: Color.fromARGB(alpha, red, green, blue),
  300: Color.fromARGB(alpha, red, green, blue),
  400: Color.fromARGB(alpha, red, green, blue),
  500: Color.fromARGB(alpha, red, green, blue),
  600: Color.fromARGB(alpha, red, green, blue),
  700: Color.fromARGB(alpha, red, green, blue),
  800: Color.fromARGB(alpha, red, green, blue),
  900: Color.fromARGB(alpha, red, green, blue),
};

 return MaterialColor(color.value, shades);
}
```

I find this very accurate in converting Color into MaterialColor

Comment: It is good if you want a single shade not a bad idea either.

Answer (score 4):

It is quite easy to use the extension method which we have in the dart, please follow the below code for the same.

```
extension ColorsExt on Color {

  MaterialColor toMaterialColor() {
    final int red = this.red;
    final int green = this.green;
    final int blue = this.blue;

    final Map<int, Color> shades = {
      50: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .1),
      100: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .2),
      200: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .3),
      300: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .4),
      400: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .5),
      500: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .6),
      600: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .7),
      700: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .8),
      800: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .9),
      900: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, 1),
    };

    return MaterialColor(value, shades);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
int colorValue = ...
Color(colorValue).toMaterialColor()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check this page,
https://gist.github.com/Nitingadhiya/58022151fb8bab45b2734f05bb70d7b3

```
 MaterialColor getMaterialColor(Color color) {
final Map<int, Color> shades = {
  50: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .1),
  100: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .2),
  200: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .3),
  300: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .4),
  400: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .5),
  500: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .6),
  600: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .7),
  700: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .8),
  800: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .9),
  900: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, 1),
};
return MaterialColor(color.value, shades);
```

}

```
var materialColor = getMaterialColor(Color(0xFF42A5F5));


print(materialColor);
```

Comment: It is the same answer of mine but in your case you set a fixed pallet for a specific color range. Each color if different. Though Idk why a palette is needed for the materialized color.